# Is it ok to use a wrapper component to pass props in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
export function injectProps() {
    const injects = {store: new Store()}; // some store

    return function (Component) {
        return class Proxy extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return React.createElement(Component, {
                    ...injects,
                    ...this.props,
                });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Is it ok to use this instead of Redux or Context API with React?

**Update:** I think I missed to point out my expectation. I'm actually passing some service(http, localStorage) to childrens only when they asks for it. It's not only about the store as services don't have any state. But I also need to pass store through it.

https://pastebin.com/G3PgVxLn

Comment: Container (or wrapper) components that pass data to presentational child components are a standard pattern when it comes to React. However, if you are using Redux (not sure if you are?), it's generally a standard pattern to map state to props within each component, that way you can get exactly the state you actually need for that component.

Comment: Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/G3PgVxLn) ?
I'm trying to pass some service to children so I can make the whole system pluggable. Not only the state store.

Comment: You've basically reinvented `recompose`'s [withProps](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withprops).

Comment: @zzzzBov What! That's... like a hidden gem  Thanks for the link 

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [this tweet](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1021850873100681221) by ***the*** Dan Abramov (React maintainer) might help.

> I understand it was probably not the point of the article. But I see
>   people reaching for Context or Redux because they don’t realize
>   components can take any children — and that often removes the need for
>   deep prop passing. Would be great to highlight!

And [Dave Ceddia](https://twitter.com/dceddia) posted a relavant React documentation link.
[Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

You can read upon those two.

And here is a demo [Nicolas Marcora](https://medium.com/@nicolasmarcora) created to show me how to pass properties to child/children.
You can pass props to children using `React.cloneElement(child,...`

*Working demo on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-l8p3bc?file=index.js).*

```js
export default class WithMouse extends React.Component {
  state = { x: 0, y: 0 }

  handleMouseMove = event => { ... }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    const childElements = React.Children.map(children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, { 
        mouse: this.state,
        onMouseMove: this.handleMouseMove 
      })
    )
    return <div>
      { childElements }
    </div>
  }
}
```

You can use [WithMouse](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-l8p3bc?file=WithMouse.js) class to pass props downward to all children and use it like following.

```js
class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <WithMouse>
        <MouseTracker />
      </WithMouse>
    );
  }
}
```

[MouseTracker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-l8p3bc?file=MouseTracker.js) has access to props passed from `WithMouse` so you can just use it without directly passing it manually.

You can probably go further and pass all props instead of a few (`mouse`, `onMouseMove`)

Comment: If I follow this approach, I'll have to add wrapper for each service and the store. There will be around 10 services. I thought of it while looking into the codes of <Provider> wrapper component.

Comment: @Rocky It seems like you want a `dependency injection`, meaning you want services to be injected to components. By `<Provider>` wrapper you mean, [Provider pattern](https://500tech.com/blog/all/dependency-injection-in-react/).? It just looks like the new Context API, but using HoC instead of Render props.

Comment: Yes, but stores doesn't work that way. As far I figured out, stores kind of attaches listeners to it's wrapper and rerwrites it's state at any change in the store. I found a way to do this but it's not the best idea I think. Using if...else.